# How to make my Form fill the entire screen on the current screen

Tags: vb.net

I'm Working on a project and i need to make the Form fill the entire screen

```
            Me.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
            Me.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
            Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
            Me.Location = New Point(Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.X, 
            Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.Y)
            Me.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
            Me.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
            Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
```

This works to fill the entire screen on whichever screen is the primary Screen, My Question is when working with more than 1 monitor (I work with 3) How can i get the screen the form is on and make it full screen on that screen and not just jump to my primary screen?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind once i drank a little more coffee...

```
        Me.Height = Screen.FromControl(Me).Bounds.Height
        Me.Width = Screen.FromControl(Me).Bounds.Width
        Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
        Me.Location = New Point(Screen.FromControl(Me).Bounds.X, 
        Screen.FromControl(Me).Bounds.Y)
        Me.Height = Screen.FromControl(Me).Bounds.Height
        Me.Width = Screen.FromControl(Me).Bounds.Width
        Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a property on the WinForm called WindowState. Set this to be Maximized. The form will automatically fill the entire monitor.

```
Form1.WindowState = Maximized
```